# Python Matlab Engine Error

Tags: python, matlab

I am using the Matlab Engine for Python.
When I try to run the command:

```
matlab.engine.find_matlab()
```

in the python prompt, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_matlab'
```

I looked into the source code of the corresponding module (matlabeninge.py), there is no 'find_matlab' method in it, or other methods listed in the Mathworks documentation.

Though I can properly start a Matlab session using:

```
matlab.engine.matlab_startup()
```

I tried reinstalling both Matlab & the Python package, nothing changed. It's as if the module lacks some code.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to follow the example listed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/matlab.engine.find_matlab.html?refresh=true)

The syntax is :

names = matlab.engine.find_matlab()

did that solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following line to solve a similar issue: (so I imported matlab.engine two times)

```
import matlab.engine
```

I called `eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab('-desktop')` after it and got the following error message without the import:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'engine'
```